# Stop call to onEndOfSpeech when converting speech to text in Android

Tags: android, speech-to-text

Is there any way to stop the call to `onEndOfSpeech` when converting speech to text, so the user will be able to speak whenever he wants to?

Comment: There is a method for this: stopListening ()

Comment: no i want to take voice input and i do not want to stop my application what i want is user should be able to speak in given time if he stop speak for some seconds then after some seconds application be able to take voice again as an input and not stop until my time has not finish

Comment: Ah, so you want 'continuous speech recognition'.

Comment: yes you are right i want continuous speech recognition if user stop to say for some seconds  so it should not stop. if user wan to speak again after some break the it should take voice as an input

Comment: please help me to get out from this problem m stuck only this functionality i want to achieve i will be very thank full if some one solve this problem